# What are some heartwarming words you can think of?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, sentence-meaning

Are there any heartwarming words you can think of? Words like "blossom," "mellow," and "melt" are good examples of what I am looking for. I don't need anything too major, just some words that make you feel "warm and fuzzy" inside.

Here are some example sentences with *italicized* heartwarming words:

"I still find single *strands of your hair* in the front seat of my car."

"As you lay in my arms, all of my worries *melt* away."

Something about those sentences just gives me chills (in a good way), so now you can somewhat "catch my drift," if you know what I mean.

Any suggestions are welcome! =)

Comment: Questions that ask for an open-ended list are not on topic here, nor are questions so obviously a matter of opinion.

Comment: @Xanne "Criticisms which do not add anything constructive" is a rule, and I know that that seems like I am breaking the "Discussion of community behavior or site policies" rule, but I wouldn't have to in the first place if you weren't putting me down and making me feel dumb. Seriously, there is no need to be rude. I don't see how they are opinion-based at all. I'm just simply asking for heartwarming words. If I can't ask this here, please tell me where I can. Is there another exchange database, because I don't want to be wasting time here if that's the case...

Comment: @AsaMatthews *'words that make you feel "warm and fuzzy" inside'* sounds very much like you are asking for people to give Opinion Based answers. The opinion in question is 'does this word make you feel "warm and fuzzy"?' You are *literally* asking for an opinion-based open-ended list of words. Xanne's comment may be curt, and to the point, but it certainly isn't objectively rude; you may just be experiencing a cultural difference (some people, especially in academia, view padding comments with "excessive niceties" to be disingenuous, condescending or patronising - i.e. rude - and this politer)